# upgrading material ui 1.x.x to 3.x.x cause typescript mismatch in withRouter

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-router, material-ui

I'm trying to upgrade Material UI version to 3.x.x and I'm getting the following type mismatch when using withRouter function. the same exact code worked with any 1.x.x version.

> TS2345: Argument of type 'ComponentType & StyledComponentProps>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ComponentType>'.   Type 'ComponentClass & StyledComponentProps, ComponentState>' is not assignable to type 'ComponentType>'.     Type 'ComponentClass & StyledComponentProps, ComponentState>' is not assignable to type 'StatelessComponent>'.       Types of property 'propTypes' are incompatible.         Type 'ValidationMap & StyledComponentProps>' has no properties in common with type 'ValidationMap>'.

code:

```
import React from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { Redirect, RouteComponentProps, withRouter } from "react-router";
import {createStyles, StyleRulesCallback, WithStyles} from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import {withStyles} from "@material-ui/core/styles/withStyles";

interface AppDataLoaderProps extends RouteComponentProps<{}> {...}

class AppDataLoader extends React.Component<AppDataLoaderProps & WithStyles, {}> {

...

}  

const styles: StyleRulesCallback = () => createStyles({...})

const mapStateToProps = (state: AppState, ownProps) => {...}
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, ownProps) => {...}

const componentWithStyles = withStyles(styles)(AppDataLoader);
const componentWithRouter = withRouter(componentWithStyles);

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps(componentWithRouter);
```

Comment: Try: `class AppDataLoader extends React.Component<AppDataLoaderProps & WithStyles & RouteComponentProps, {}>`. Without extending AppDataLoaderProps